# Limit of an integral over different interval

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, confidence-interval

Knowing that 
$$
\left(1+ \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n e^{-t\sqrt{n}}
 = e^{-t^2/2} \exp\left( n\int_0^{t/\sqrt{n}} \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} - \sigma\right)^2 \frac{1}{(1+\sigma)^3}d\sigma\right),
$$
I call $f(t) =  e^{-t^2/2}$ and $f_n(t) = \left(1+ \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n e^{-t\sqrt{n}}$.

How to justify

a) $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\sqrt[7]n}^0 (f_n(t) - f(t)) dt = 0$$

b) same question but over a different interval of integration $[-\sqrt n, -\sqrt[7]n]$ and $(-\infty, -\sqrt n]$.

Where comes this $\sqrt[7]n$ from?

Thank you!

Comment: You're asking about the origin of the limit $-\sqrt[7]{n}$.  What is the context of your question?  Indeed, a reader might ask you "Why is the lower limit $-\sqrt[7]{n}$?

Comment: I would like to know how to justify the limit a). And I don't really know where this $-\sqrt[7]n$ comes from.

That's the reason why I don't know where to start to answer this question.

Comment: I have a hint: we can use $0 \le 1-e^{-x} \le x$ for $x \ge 0$

Comment: You sure it should be $$\sqrt[7]n$$ instead of $$\sqrt[t]n$$